# Xml-pdf npm ,Using a mustache template with xml for creating pdf file with nodeJs

Tags: node.js, templates, pdf-generation, mustache

I create mustache template and I access to all data in xml, and i convert this template to pdf with xml-pdf, but I can't add automatic page Number (pagination).
And if the page is full it adds a new page (automatically),  so can I detect this new page and give it a specific layout, for example (margin-top)??
Or can I give a specific layout page for all pages with CSS or JS included in the template. Mustache?
Any solution please?
Thank you.

> ```
> Mustache template:
>
>
>
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
> <head>
>   <title>XML-PDF</title>
>   <style type="text/css">
>           table {
>         border-collapse: collapse;
>         border-spacing: 0; }
>       td,
>       th {
>         padding: 0; }
>       table, th, td {
>         border: none; }
>       table {
>         width: 100%;
>         display: table; }
>         table.bordered > thead > tr,
>         table.bordered > tbody > tr {
>           border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0; }
>         table.striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) {
>           background-color: #f2f2f2; }
>         table.striped > tbody > tr > td {
>           border-radius: 0; }
>         table.highlight > tbody > tr {
>           transition: background-color .25s ease; }
>           table.highlight > tbody > tr:hover {
>             background-color: #f2f2f2; }
>         table.centered thead tr th, table.centered tbody tr td {
>           text-align: center; }
>       thead {
>         border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0; }
>       td, th {
>         padding: 15px 5px;
>         display: table-cell;
>         text-align: left;
>         vertical-align: middle;
>         border-radius: 2px; }
>   </style>
> </head>
> <body>
>   <table class="striped">
>       <thead>
>           <tr>
>               <th>COMMON</th>
>               <th>BOTANICAL</th>
>               <th>ZONE</th>
>               <th>LIGHT</th>
>               <th>PRICE</th>
>               <th>AVAILABILITY</th>
>           </tr>
>       </thead>
>       <tbody>
>       {{#CATALOG.PLANT}}
>           <tr>
>             <td>{{COMMON}}</td>
>             <td>{{BOTANICAL}}</td>
>             <td>{{ZONE}}</td>
>             <td>{{LIGHT}}</td>
>             <td>{{PRICE}}</td>
>             <td>{{AVAILABILITY}}</td>
>           </tr>
>         {{/CATALOG.PLANT}}
>         </tbody>
>   </table>
>
> <section
>       style="margin-left: 12%; page-break-before: always;margin-top:2em"
>     >
> {{#CATALOG.PLANT}}
>   <ul>
>       <li>{{COMMON}}</li>
>         <li>{{BOTANICAL}}</li>
>         <li>{{ZONE}}</li>
>         <li>{{LIGHT}}</li>
>         <li>{{PRICE}}</li>
>         <li>{{AVAILABILITY}}</li>
>   </ul>
> {{/CATALOG.PLANT}}
> </section>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

> ```
> XML file :
>
>
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <CATALOG>
>   <PLANT>
>     <COMMON>Bloodroot</COMMON>
>     <BOTANICAL>Sanguinaria canadensis</BOTANICAL>
>     <ZONE>4</ZONE>
>     <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
>     <PRICE>$2.44</PRICE>
>     <AVAILABILITY>031599</AVAILABILITY>
>   </PLANT>
>   <PLANT>
>     <COMMON>Columbine</COMMON>
>     <BOTANICAL>Aquilegia canadensis</BOTANICAL>
>     <ZONE>3</ZONE>
>     <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
>     <PRICE>$9.37</PRICE>
>     <AVAILABILITY>030699</AVAILABILITY>
>   </PLANT>
>   <PLANT>
>     <COMMON>Marsh Marigold</COMMON>
>     <BOTANICAL>Caltha palustris</BOTANICAL>
>     <ZONE>4</ZONE>
>     <LIGHT>Mostly Sunny</LIGHT>
>     <PRICE>$6.81</PRICE>
>     <AVAILABILITY>051799</AVAILABILITY>
>   </PLANT>
>   <PLANT>
>     <COMMON>Cowslip</COMMON>
>     <BOTANICAL>Caltha palustris</BOTANICAL>
>     <ZONE>4</ZONE>
>     <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
>     <PRICE>$9.90</PRICE>
>     <AVAILABILITY>030699</AVAILABILITY>
>   </PLANT>
>   <PLANT>
>     <COMMON>Dutchman's-Breeches</COMMON>
>     <BOTANICAL>Dicentra cucullaria</BOTANICAL>
>     <ZONE>3</ZONE>
>     <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
>     <PRICE>$6.44</PRICE>
>     <AVAILABILITY>012099</AVAILABILITY>
>   </PLANT>
>   <PLANT>
>     <COMMON>Ginger, Wild</COMMON>
>     <BOTANICAL>Asarum canadense</BOTANICAL>
>     <ZONE>3</ZONE>
>     <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
>     <PRICE>$9.03</PRICE>
>     <AVAILABILITY>041899</AVAILABILITY>
>   </PLANT>
>   <PLANT>
>     <COMMON>Hepatica</COMMON>
>     <BOTANICAL>Hepatica americana</BOTANICAL>
>     <ZONE>4</ZONE>
>     <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
>     <PRICE>$4.45</PRICE>
>     <AVAILABILITY>012699</AVAILABILITY>
>   </PLANT>
>   <PLANT>
>     <COMMON>Liverleaf</COMMON>
>     <BOTANICAL>Hepatica americana</BOTANICAL>
>     <ZONE>4</ZONE>
>     <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
>     <PRICE>$3.99</PRICE>
>     <AVAILABILITY>010299</AVAILABILITY>
>   </PLANT>
>   <PLANT>
>     <COMMON>Jack-In-The-Pulpit</COMMON>
>     <BOTANICAL>Arisaema triphyllum</BOTANICAL>
>     <ZONE>4</ZONE>
>     <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
>     <PRICE>$3.23</PRICE>
>     <AVAILABILITY>020199</AVAILABILITY>
>   </PLANT>
>   <PLANT>
>     <COMMON>Mayapple</COMMON>
>     <BOTANICAL>Podophyllum peltatum</BOTANICAL>
>     <ZONE>3</ZONE>
>     <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
>     <PRICE>$2.98</PRICE>
>     <AVAILABILITY>060599</AVAILABILITY>
>   </PLANT>
>   <PLANT>
>     <COMMON>Phlox, Woodland</COMMON>
>     <BOTANICAL>Phlox divaricata</BOTANICAL>
>     <ZONE>3</ZONE>
>     <LIGHT>Sun or Shade</LIGHT>
>     <PRICE>$2.80</PRICE>
>     <AVAILABILITY>012299</AVAILABILITY>
>   </PLANT>
>   <PLANT>
>     <COMMON>Phlox, Blue</COMMON>
>     <BOTANICAL>Phlox divaricata</BOTANICAL>
>     <ZONE>3</ZONE>
>     <LIGHT>Sun or Shade</LIGHT>
>     <PRICE>$5.59</PRICE>
>     <AVAILABILITY>021699</AVAILABILITY>
>   </PLANT>
>   <PLANT>
>     <COMMON>Spring-Beauty</COMMON>
>     <BOTANICAL>Claytonia Virginica</BOTANICAL>
>     <ZONE>7</ZONE>
>     <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
>     <PRICE>$6.59</PRICE>
>     <AVAILABILITY>020199</AVAILABILITY>
>   </PLANT>
>   <PLANT>
>     <COMMON>Trillium</COMMON>
>     <BOTANICAL>Trillium grandiflorum</BOTANICAL>
>     <ZONE>5</ZONE>
>     <LIGHT>Sun or Shade</LIGHT>
>     <PRICE>$3.90</PRICE>
>     <AVAILABILITY>042999</AVAILABILITY>
>   </PLANT>
>   
>  
>
>   
>   
>
> </CATALOG>
> ```

> ```
> index.js
>
>
>
> const xml = require("xml-pdf");
> var options = { "-h": "500m" };
>
> xml.xmlpdf(
>   "./in.xml",
>   "./output.pdf",
>   "./template.mustache",
>   options,
>   function (error, response) {
>     if (error) {
>       console.log(error);
>     } else {
>       console.log(response);
>     }
>   }
> );
> ```

output pdf example :

[[image: output pdf example :]]

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
var options = { "-h": "500m", "pdf": {"border": "10mm" /* whatever space you need */ };
```